# Automatically writing scatterplots in ggplot2 to a folder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large number of variables and would like to create scatterplots comparing all variables to a single variable. I have been able to do this in base R using `lapply`, but I cannot complete the same task in `ggplot2` using `lapply`.

Below is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,12,14,15,16)
df$B <- c(5,6,7,8,9,10,13,15,14,15,16,17,18,18,19,20)
df$C <- c(11,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
```

I define the variables I would like to generate scatterplots with, using the code below:

```
df_col_names <- df %>% select(A:C) %>% colnames(.)
```

Below is how I have been able to successfully complete the task of plotting all variables against variable A, using `lapply` in base R:

```
lapply(df_col_names, function(x) {
  tiff(filename=sprintf("C:\\Documents\\%s.tiff", x),
       width = 1000, height = 1000, res=200)
  plot(df$A, df[[x]], 
       pch=19,
       cex = 1.5,
       ylab = x,
       ylim = c(0, 20),
       xlim = c(0, 20))
  dev.off()
})
```

Below is my attempt at completing the task in ggplot2 without any success. It generates the tiff images, although they are empty.

```
lapply(df_col_names, function(x) {
  tiff(filename=sprintf("C:\\Documents\\%s.tiff", x),
       width = 1000, height = 1000, res=200)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(data = df,
             aes(x = A, y = df_col_names[[x]], size = 3)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = A, y = df_col_names[[x]], size = 0), method = "lm", size=0.5) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = c(0, 20), ylim = c(0, 20)) +
  guides(size = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
dev.off()
})
```

Comment: You need to explicitly call `print` if you want to plot ggplots inside a function call. However, I recommend switching to `ggsave` for ease of use.

Comment: Can you try using `ggsave` to save the plots, instead of writing to the graphics device directly? So instead of `tiff("file.tiff"); ggplot(...); dev.off()` you'd use `gg <- ggplot(); ggsave("file.tiff", gg)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with `ggsave`. Also note that you are passing string column names to `ggplot` so use `.data` to refer to actual column values.

```
library(ggplot2)

lapply(df_col_names, function(x) {
  ggplot(df) +
    geom_point( aes(x = A, y = .data[[x]], size = 3)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = A, y = .data[[x]], size = 0), method = "lm", size=0.5) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = 1, xlim = c(0, 20), ylim = c(0, 20)) +
    guides(size = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 14) -> plt
  ggsave(sprintf("%s.tiff", x), plt)
})
```